# Installing kernel breaks apt

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, compiling

I tried to do something which I hoped was very simple: re-compile the existing kernel version with one modified config option.

I followed the directions on [this wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel), which seem to be the most up-to-date of the several pages you'll find on the Ubuntu wiki alone which related to compiling the kernel (there were more comprehensive pages, but they were often a half-decade out of date).

The compile worked OK, and I named my kernel version `4.4.0-57.78+foo` - I did this by modifying the `debian/changelog` file, which originally had a first line like:

```
linux (4.4.0-57.78) xenial; urgency=low
```

to:

```
linux (4.4.0-57.78+foo) xenial; urgency=low
```

I have no idea if that's correct, as the documentation is not clear on this point (e.g., if I should *replace* the `.78` part or add to it).

This created a bunch of `.deb` files, namely:

```
linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-57_4.4.0-57.78+foo_amd64.deb          linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic_4.4.0-57.78+foo_amd64.deb
linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-57-generic_4.4.0-57.78+foo_amd64.deb  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic_4.4.0-57.78+foo_amd64.deb
linux-cloud-tools-common_4.4.0-57.78+foo_all.deb              linux-source-4.4.0_4.4.0-57.78+foo_all.deb
linux-doc_4.4.0-57.78+foo_all.deb                             linux-tools-4.4.0-57_4.4.0-57.78+foo_amd64.deb
linux-headers-4.4.0-57_4.4.0-57.78+foo_all.deb                linux-tools-4.4.0-57-generic_4.4.0-57.78+foo_amd64.deb
linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic_4.4.0-57.78+foo_amd64.deb      linux-tools-common_4.4.0-57.78+foo_all.deb
```

I installed these using:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../linux-*foo*.deb
```

Now, `apt-get` is broken. Every command (e.g., `sudo apt-get install <whatever>` complains about:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-57-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic (= 4.4.0-57.78) but 4.4.0-57.78+foo is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How can I satisfy `apt-get` in this case? Most of the references to this error message are about broken apt-get state, but it's not clear how it applies here. The messages referring to 'linux-signed-image*' are interested - on a locally built kernel, these modules are not available (perhaps these a modules meant for secure-boot scenarios, and clearly I can't sign those?).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install compiled kernel alongside existing kernels](http://askubuntu.com/questions/870829/install-compiled-kernel-alongside-existing-kernels)

Comment: @Pilot6 - two separate questions because people get _very_ particular about the specific question, etc. This one is about how to recover from the situation where my kernel install broke `apt`. Your answer there might be more appropriate over here (although, of course, you can't use a non `-f` `apt` command to fix `apt` in this case, but it's on the right track.