# Install compiled kernel alongside existing kernels

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I would like to compile a version of my existing Ubuntu kernel, and install it *alongside* my existing kernel version. I hoped this was very simple!

I followed the directions on [this wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel), which seem to be the most up-to-date of the several pages you'll find on the Ubuntu wiki regarding this task.

The compile worked OK, and I named my kernel version `4.4.0-57.78+foo` - I did this by modifying the `debian/changelog` file, which originally had a first line like:

```
linux (4.4.0-57.78) xenial; urgency=low
```

to:

```
linux (4.4.0-57.78+foo) xenial; urgency=low
```

I have no idea if that's correct, as the documentation is not clear on this point (e.g., if I should *replace* the `.78` part or add to it).

This created a bunch of `.deb` files, namely:

```
linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-57_4.4.0-57.78+foo_amd64.deb          linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic_4.4.0-57.78+foo_amd64.deb
linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-57-generic_4.4.0-57.78+foo_amd64.deb  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic_4.4.0-57.78+foo_amd64.deb
linux-cloud-tools-common_4.4.0-57.78+foo_all.deb              linux-source-4.4.0_4.4.0-57.78+foo_all.deb
linux-doc_4.4.0-57.78+foo_all.deb                             linux-tools-4.4.0-57_4.4.0-57.78+foo_amd64.deb
linux-headers-4.4.0-57_4.4.0-57.78+foo_all.deb                linux-tools-4.4.0-57-generic_4.4.0-57.78+foo_amd64.deb
linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic_4.4.0-57.78+foo_amd64.deb      linux-tools-common_4.4.0-57.78+foo_all.deb
```

I installed these using:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../linux-*foo*.deb
```

Now, as it happens, something is wrong and my kernel doesn't boot - but, worse, it appears the install has overwritten my existing `.57` kernel.

How can I install my custom kernel as an option at boot, without blowing away my existing kernel?

FWIW, my `dpkg --list 'linux-image*'` output looks like:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                   Version                  Architecture             Description
+++-======================================-========================-========================-=================================================================================
un  linux-image                            <none>                   <none>                   (no description available)
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-15-generic           4.4.0-15.31              amd64                    Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-18-generic           4.4.0-18.34              amd64                    Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic           4.4.0-21.37              amd64                    Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-22-generic           4.4.0-22.40              amd64                    Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic           4.4.0-24.43              amd64                    Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic           4.4.0-31.50              amd64                    Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic           4.4.0-36.55              amd64                    Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic           4.4.0-38.57              amd64                    Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic           4.4.0-42.62              amd64                    Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic           4.4.0-43.63              amd64                    Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic           4.4.0-45.66              amd64                    Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic           4.4.0-47.68              amd64                    Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic           4.4.0-51.72              amd64                    Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic           4.4.0-53.74              amd64                    Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic           4.4.0-57.78+foo     amd64                    Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-15-generic     4.4.0-15.31              amd64                    Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-18-generic     4.4.0-18.34              amd64                    Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic     4.4.0-21.37              amd64                    Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic     4.4.0-22.40              amd64                    Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic     4.4.0-24.43              amd64                    Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic     4.4.0-31.50              amd64                    Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic     4.4.0-36.55              amd64                    Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic     4.4.0-38.57              amd64                    Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-42-generic     4.4.0-42.62              amd64                    Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-43-generic     4.4.0-43.63              amd64                    Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic     4.4.0-45.66              amd64                    Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic     4.4.0-47.68              amd64                    Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic     4.4.0-51.72              amd64                    Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic     4.4.0-53.74              amd64                    Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic     4.4.0-57.78+foo     amd64                    Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                    4.4.0.57.60              amd64                    Generic Linux kernel image
```

Note in particular that my `+foo` kernel shows up as the *only* .57 kernel, so it apparently overwrote my existing `.57` kernel.

Comment: It appears your kernel is installed but not booting. Support for custom kernel is limited. Not sure what or why you are compiling a kernel but I have some general tips here - http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/kernel

Comment: Creating custom kernels is off topic here.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - where is it on-topic?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for general programming questions.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - it's definitely not a general programming question. I'm asking about compiling an Ubunut-specific kernel, following a guide on the Ubuntu wiki. Furthermore, I checked the help/FAQ and it seems that this specific question is on-topic (but support on issues which arise from actually using a kernel with non-standard options would be limited).

Comment: ... furthermore, to clarify, my question is actually about `apt` and `linux-image` - how to install an image side-by-side an existing kernel, without clobbering it.

Comment: I would think most of the people there would have compiled the kernel.

Comment: As it is already said, the kernel is installed, but is not booting. Maybe it is because something is wrong with the custom kernel, or maybe Secure Boot is on.

Comment: @Pilot6 - thanks. I probably confused this question by asking two separate questions (a) how to install the custom kernel _alongside_ the existing version and (b) why is it not booting? I really meant for it to be about (a). I will carve off (b) into a separate question.

Comment: You installed it correctly, so (a) is solved. (b) is off-topic. We do not know what you did with the kernel and why it does not boot.

Comment: @Pilot6 no, (a) is not solved - it has _overwritten_ my existing `.57` kernel and I can no longer boot it. I want to know how to have both stock `.57` and `.57-foo` installed, so when `.57-foo` doesn't boot I don't have to resort to hacking out questions on my phone :)

Comment: I install custom kernels the same way and they DO boot. So....

Comment: My question is not about it booting (please note that I've edited it). My question is why did it _replace_ my existing kernel, in the grub boot options, in the `dpkg` output, etc, etc. I want to have both `.57` and `.57-foo` as separate and available `vmlinuz` files, just like `.53` and `.57` can be side-by-side.

Comment: You changed the question. Yes, it did overwrite your 57 kernel, because it has the same abi. You can remove your custom deb packages and update the system. You should get the official kernel right back.

Comment: Yes, I _clarified_ the question based on your concerns, by making very small edits - but the substance (and headline question/title) was always the same: how to install one kernel _alongside_ the existing one. You can check the edit history using the links below the question!

Comment: Remove your broken kernel and all will be OK.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix [The current consensus is pretty strong that building and installing custom kernels is *not* off-topic for Ask Ubuntu.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5576/do-custom-kernels-constitute-off-topicness) (Top 2 answers for allowing are scored 11 and 13; top two answers for not allowing are 3 and 3.)

Comment: @EliahKagan Yeah, I got railroaded by the Fabby Freight Train over the last few months on custom kernels. I'm all on-board now though :)